# How to change the data structure used in CFS

Tags: c, ubuntu, data-structures, linux-kernel, scheduling

Can anybody tell me how to change the data structure(RB tree) used in Completely Fair Scheduler? I wish to implement different data structures to see how they perform.I know one way is to alter the rbtree.h & rbtee.c in the Kernel source. But I am not sure how to do it or is it safe. I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Does it sound like a good idea to take code in a file named "rbtree" and make it NOT a rbtree? It doesn't sound like a good idea to me! Just change the variable definitions used by CFS to some other data structure. And all of the functions used to manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

Download the kernel source code. Make the needed edits and compile. Then install is. It should do it. Back up your current kernel, just in case.